# Installing crank on threadfit30

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I wanted to get advice regarding installation of new bottom bracket and crank.

1. My frame BB shell is BSA68.
2. Bottom bracket is threadfit 30
3. crank is eewings mountain (which expects a BSA73).

I looked at both of the manuals: [chris king](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2920/2114/files/bb_fit_guide_r1.pdf?v=1632265266) and [eewings](https://canecreek.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/eeWings-MTN_8_8_2023.pdf).

I tried to find the matching setup from chris king, and I believe it is:
*1 | 2.5 | 5 | 1 (wide)* 
**(non drive spindle spacer | non drive cup | drive cup spacer| drive spindle spacers)**

Then I looked at the eewings manual.
Seems like the relevant entry is: 
*2.5mm (Bottom Bracket Spacer)
1.75mm (eeWings Spindle Spacer)*

I attach the manuals

**bottom bracket:**
[image]

**eewings:**
[image]

I got a bit confused.
I think I should use the

**2.5 | 5**

**non drive cup | drive cup spacer** of chris king, but then I am not sure about the spindle spacers? should it be 1 | 1 from each side, only 1.75 on driveside as recommended by eewings, or something else?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Try the Chris King instructions first. If it isn't right, (too loose, too tight) try again. The tolerances on these things are usually such that some micro-shimming (tiny spacers) are often employed to get a "perfect" fit.

Comment: Alright, will try that first. Thank you!